# How to convert ts files to js

Tags: typescript

I want to convert my typescript files to js files. That works fine when I convert it using

```
nodemon --watch assets/ts --exec tsc assets/ts/*.ts --outDir assets/js
```

but when I try to import a class it converts it to `require()`. How can I keep the import like it was before?

```
import {Testclass} from "./test";

//result
var test1 = require("./test");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the module system that the compiler uses. ([See here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module) all the allowed options)

So add `"module": "es2015"` to your `tsconfig.json` (if it exists), or add it to the command:

```
nodemon --watch assets/ts --exec tsc assets/ts/*.ts --outDir assets/js --module es2015
```